# Rooted Kindle Fire - Mounting Filesystem from Ubuntu

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, cyanogenmod, linux, amazon-kindle-fire

I have a first gen Kindle Fire that has been flashed with Android 4.0.4 (hashcode's of course).

The device was rooted using my thoshiba NB305 netbook running ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid).

While the original OS was still installed, I could mount the kindle's filesystem over a usb connection using

```
 mount -t ext3 /dev/sdc /mnt/kfire
```

Now I'm trying perform another rooting operation from the same laptop, to upgrade android to 4.2.2, and cannot get the kindle's file system mounted with this command.

I checked dmesg and the devices is still being detected as SCSI device on /dev/sdc

```
 sd 11:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

however, a

```
 ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/
```

reveals that

```
 usb-Am_File-CD_Gadget_0123456789ABCDEF-0:0 -> ../../sdc
```

The thing is, mount isn't even detecting that a device is present at /dev/sdc,
I simply get the error

```
 mount: no medium found on /dev/sdc
```

I'm not sure how to mount a usb-Am_File-CD_Gadget, or why I'm not at lest getting a "wrong filesystem type" error from mount.

Also, the kindle is not showing up when running

```
 adb devices
```

and so figured I needed to mount it in order for adb to be able to see it. However, I just tried my LS970, and its showing up in adb devices, but also cannot be mounted with the above command (or mtpfs -o allow_other /mnt/kfire).

**So, I'm looking to get the kindle discovered and communicating with adb first and foremost (I thought mounting was required for this, but apparently isn't).**

---

I found this article to be potentially helpful, but still need to give it a through reading:

https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php/How_to_use_USB_CDC_ACM_and_MS_composite_Linux_gadget_driver

Any help is much appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the micro-usb cable I was using to connect the kindle to my laptop.

Once I found my uber quality ASUS cable, progress began...

Now the OS atleast properly detecting the device, and loading it as a mass USB storage device.

**dmesg:**

```
[ 5516.756143] usb 1-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 125
[ 5516.824377] hub 1-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1
[ 5517.216091] usb 2-1: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 21
[ 5517.355193] usb 2-1: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[ 5517.383505] usb 2-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[ 5517.405589] scsi4 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
[ 5517.411906] usb-storage: device found at 21
[ 5517.411919] usb-storage: waiting for device to settle before scanning
[ 5522.409318] usb-storage: device scan complete
[ 5522.412282] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Am       File-CD Gadget   0000 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 5522.415038] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 5522.433234] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

However, adb devices now gave:

```
List of devices attached 
????????????    no permissions
```

to get ADB to properly list the device, and be able to connect to it, please see this solution on SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510284/adb-devices-command-not-working